# dual booted Ubuntu with the windows 10 on Ubuntu showing "no Bluetooth found"

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth

I have dual booted Ubuntu with windows 10 but on Ubuntu it is showing "no bluetooth found".

On windows I disable fast boot still it wont work.

1. I have tried enabling the Bluetooth in boot menu, but network adapter setting is disabled there (! is present before the network adapter)
2. I have tried updating the linux firmware on Ubuntu but it is also not working.

Comment: Disable "Fast Startup". Fast Boot is something else

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep bluez` show?